# Accordion inside tinyscrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have built accordion inside tinyscroll bar div. But the problem is tiny scrollbar is not extending (height) when the accordion menu opens.

Here is my code

```
$('#test').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').show();
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
     $('#overlay').show();
});
//Accordion
    $('#accordion-3').dcAccordion({
        eventType: 'click',
        autoClose: true,
        saveState: false,
        disableLink: false,
        showCount: false,
        speed: 'slow'
    });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GknfT/5/)**

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline-table;`? For instance, `#scrollbar1 .viewport {
    display: inline-table;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}`

Comment: you need to call `$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar_update();` once the accordion has finished its animation.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar_update();` once the accordion has finished its animation, like so:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AFaQ/)

```
$('#test').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').show();
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
     $('#overlay').show();
});
//Accordion
    $('#accordion-3').dcAccordion({
        eventType: 'click',
        autoClose: true,
        saveState: false,
        disableLink: false,
        showCount: false,
        speed: '400'
    });

$("#accordion-3").on("click", function() {
    window.setTimeout( function() { 
        $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar_update();
    } , 400 );
});
```

I don't think dcAccordion has any sort of callback feature, so you're stuck with `setTimeout`